# sudo: unable to change to root gid

Tags: sudo, guest-session

[image]

Running `sudo <command>` failed with:

> sudo: unable to change to root gid

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is and why you try to run these commands or what you expect to happen. Please [edit] your question and state what your problem is. Note that this site is English only.

Comment: @LiveWireBT the hint is in the username at the prompt ;-)

Comment: Luckily Rinzwind caught it, but next time please put more effort in writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here: a GUEST account does not have "sudo" permissions.

You need to log out and use the admin account to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most installations of programs require the sudo command that gives admin permissions. As a guest you have very limited access to ubuntu and are not allowed to install programs. Log out and use another user account or re-install and create an admin account>